# Can I ask this question with the preposition 'under'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

Sentence:

> What do you mean **under** this number?

I want to find out what the person means using some number.

Example:

> Tom: 300.
>   Sam: What do you mean **under** 300?

I'd like to know what this number means, what the number is about.

So, can I ask this question with the preposition 'under'?

Comment: Sorry Max, I do not really understand this question. If you are **under** the age of majority, you are unable to vote. This means if the voting age is 18, you cannot vote until you reach that birthday. If you are over the age of consent, you may consent to join the army or to get married without parental permission. You can be over six feet tall or under five feet tall. You can have more or less marbles in the bowls.

Comment: @Willow I'm pretty sure he's asking if "under" could be used instead of "by", e.g.: "What do you mean under 300?" instead of "What do you mean by 300?" -- Some languages, like Hungarian, construct similar sentences in a way that if you translated them word-by-word, you'd end up with sentences having the word "under" where English uses the word "by".

Comment: @Korvin you are completely right